# Fast, big and extensible geometry library for C++

Tags: c++, c, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

I've searched a lot of topics and came across lot of topics like 'easy of use geometry library'.

I'm searching something other than this. 
I plan to write complex application for processing 3D data (lets say something like blender, 3ds max, maya or houdini). I'm looking for the best available geometry library available to use in my project (it could be free or commercial). I dont care if it is easy to use or it is hard and complex.

On top of this library I would like to build basic functionality of this application (like modeling, boolean operations, triangulaton, texturing, retopologing tools etc).

The keys are:

- it should be fast
- it should be extensible (In long term meaning - if it does not provide some functionality - it should be good base for further development)
- it should allow to handle most of geometry types (triangles, polygons, degenerated elements)
- it should have a lot of implemented algorithms for processing this geometry
- it would be great if it could process NURBS, Bezier curves, point clouds, voxels etc.

**Of course this could be not a single library. But then it would be great if these libraries will work seamlessly together.**

I know there is boost:geometry, CGAL, OpenMesh and PCL. Is there any alternative?

Comment: How much is "big" for you? :)

Comment: I'm sorry for not being precise enough. Big means that its functions should be comparable to functions of geometry libraries of Sidefx Houdini or Autodesk Maya. Sidefx Houdini library is very big (but you cannot buy it with sourcesand I would like to extend it in the future). It is used by the biggest film studios around the world (Pixar, Disney) to write tools to batch-process geometry.

Comment: Look at my comment on your other question - in your case the question isn't what's the best library but how well you can abstract it because from your plans it looks like you have a long way to go. Plan for change and start small.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I need library that could be easly extended AND has lot of "stuff" already implemented.
(for readers: the other mentioned question by you is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621030/3d-opengl-viewport-library-in-c#comment15388879_11621030)

Comment: On first glance you are looking for something that is closer to computer graphics than computational geometry. Is that right? `Houdini` and `Autodesk Maya` are complete applications. It's hard to compare them to libraries.

Comment: no, I'm looking for library. Maya, Houdini etc are developed on top of computional geometry libratries. If you look into maya API or houdinis HDK (http://www.sidefx.com/docs/hdk11.0/hdk_geometry_intro.html), you can see exactly what I mean. I want to build my custom "full feature" application, that would on the beginning be able to process 3d data and I want to build it on top of library that would give me a kick start into this task.

Comment: Judging from your requirements you have already listed all likely options. I'd suggest you gather a preliminary list of algorithms you want to use and then check against the libraries.

Comment: I have heard about these libraries but I have never used them. The purpose of this question was to find out which of these or other libraries (if they could be better than these) suits best my needs AND to find out which one should I take to be sure it will be extensible and will be good base for developing more complex algorithms. I've never used any of them so any information which one is more abstract, faster, handles better geometry, ... is very helpfull :)

Comment: Have you considered VTK and ITK? Powerful and extensible.

Comment: I havent heard about it before. It seems that VTK is useful for visualisation data (not for processing it like modeling) but it contains some processing algorithms. Anyway thank you for this info because it could be very usefull for visualising things :)

Comment: What functionality do the libraries listed by you (boost:geometry, CGAL, OpenMesh and PCL) miss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need really `BIG` (CAD grade) libraries for all-around geometry manipulations take a look at these two:

1. [ACIS](http://www.spatial.com/products/3d-acis-modeling) from Spatial Corporation: doc.spatial.com/qref/ACIS/html/
2. [Parasolid](http://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/en_us/products/open/parasolid/?stc=usiia400121&gclid=CL3Ouqmgt7ECFc0vmAodLwgA8g) from Siemens

Both libraries are used in high-end 3D modelling software.

Comment: thanky you! I haven't heard about them before. Do you know which "high-end 3D" software uses them?

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasolid - among others: Delcam, Unigraphics, SolidEdge, SolidWorks. ACIS is used in CATIA and was used in AutoCAD.

Comment: Thank you! Additional do you know what geometry library blender bases on? (I suppose it bases on some external library)

Comment: Blender is open-source. Take a look: http://www.blender.org/download/source-code/

Comment: Thank you. Do you know which library is Autodesk Maya, 3ds max or Sidef Houdini based on? Or they implement their completely custom library from the ground up?

Comment: Autodesk used ACIS for some time (~2006). I don't know what they use now.